# Perl: start command not found when running perl script using cygwin perl (Windows)

Tags: windows, perl, cygwin

Below is the code of setup.pl:

```
my  $fileToCopy= "ewq_file.bat";
my $destination = $ENV{PREPARE};   ### $destination = C:\Windows
if ( -f "$destination\\$fileToCopy" ) {
    print "Triggering $destination\\$fileToCopy\n";
    system("start $destination\\$fileToCopy"); 
}
```

On triggering: `C:\cygwin\bin\perl.exe setup.pl`

Output:

```
Triggering C:\Windows\ewq_file.bat
sh: start: command not found
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

You're using a unix build of Perl in a unix emulation environment. `system` thus uses `sh` unless you tell it otherwise. But `start` is a `cmd` builtin.

```perl
system( "cmd", "/c", "start", "", "$destination\\$fileToCopy" );

die( "Can't launch shell: $!\n"                   ) if $? == -1;
die( "Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" ) if $? & 0x7F;
die( "Child exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n"  ) if $? >> 8;
```